# Receiving sound from a startech 7.1 usb external sound card with spdif digital audio drivers

Tags: recording, digital, technology, digital-technology

So I installed all the drivers for it but I can't seem to receive sound from it. I'll outline my setup so it'll be easier for someone to help me. I have a female XLR to aux running from my behringer x32 board into the line in input on the startech card. Then I have the cord that came with it plugged in here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikApu.jpg

The cord that plugs into that ends in a usb which I have plugged into my PC. When I open up my recording devices it shows it there, but it shows that they can't be used(shown in picture below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ85C.jpg

I've tried for so long but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong? Is the cord on the back of the startech card just a power cord and do I need to run another cord out or is it something different?

Comment: I know next to nothing about these particular devices, but you say you have an XLR->aux comming from the x32 to the Line In on the sound card. Where exactly is it connected to the x32? This could be a mismatch.

Comment: I'm plugging it into the out on the monitor mix

Comment: But there are two mono balanced XLR monitor mix outs(L&R) on the x32,  and a single, stereo(3-pin) 3.5mm jack on the sound card, right? If this is right, they can't be connected(balanced/unbalanced). Is this how you have connected them?

Comment: @n00dles I was just using the right output on the x32 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have connected a balanced mono output(XLR) to an unbalanced stereo input(3.5mm stereo jack).

You need a sound card that accepts two balanced line-level inputs(XLR or TRS). The Startech 7.1 only has a stereo line-level input(unbalanced), and two microphone inputs(Mic-level). This isn't a professional sound card.

I have checked the documentation for the x32, and as a workaround, *I think* you could use the TRS outputs as unbalanced outputs. Then you only need a lead to take two mono 6.35mm jacks to a stereo 3.5mm jack(Line-In). [This is a budget example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/3-5mm-Stereo-6-35mm-Audio-Cable/dp/B0034DSUMK). You could use two 6.35mm mono jack leads, and a dual mono 6.35mm jack to 3.5mm stereo jack lead if it's easier. This is not ideal, but it's a workaround.

Hopefully, the sound card should show up as active in 'Playback Devices' then, but to test it for now, you should try plugging something else into it. Something that has a line-level unbalanced output. Which is most consumer audio products.